# Why does the text of an <a> element of <li> become transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Im making an angular project using bootstrap with the navbar that becomes fixed on scroll. I dunno why, but when I scroll down to this block, the text of an li element becomes transparent and it seems that the navbar doesn't even exist. On the first image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjBnv.png) all elements hover as it should be, but on the second one [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7bhS.png) it looks like the block with selected text overcomes the navbar. You might recon those directives I made, but they're not the point.

```
<div appHeader class="container-fluid p-2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(197, 197, 197)">
  <div appNavbar class="navbar">
    <ul [@appearingItems] class="ml-1 nav row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item ml-2">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" routerLink="home"><i class="bi-house" style="font-size: 2em;"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" routerLink="city-information">О городе</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" routerLink="news">Новости</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" routerLink="ads">Объявления</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" routerLink="organizations">Организации</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have tried to change the `z-index` of your `.container-fluid` or to it's parent that is at the same level of the bloc overlapping your menu ?

Comment: Without seeing your CSS my guess would be: there is something wrong with your CSS...

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?